# disable button in react JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to disable multiple buttons once Button1 is clicked. But only Button1 is disabled and somehow Button2 is not. 
Please help. Thank you!

```
    <button disabled={this.props.submitting} className="button1" type="submit" onClick={(e)=>this._handleButton1(e)}>
        <IndexLink activeClassName="activeLink" to='/button1'>Button1</IndexLink>
    </button>

    <button disabled={this.props.submitting} className="button2" type="button" onClick={(e)=>this._handleButton2(e)}>
        <IndexLink activeClassName="activeLink" to='/button2'>Button2</IndexLink>
    </button>
```

_handleButton1 and _handleButton2 are like:

```
_handleButton1(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.function1();
}
```

function1 is passed through map dispatch to props since I am using Redux. Other part of the code are working fine. Button1 is being properly disabled so that shows this.props.submitting is being set correctly by my Redux action & reducer. It seems like a HTML issue.

Comment: can't make sense of this snippet , please add more functions definitions .

Comment: If you are using an onClick event on button to call the `_handleButton1` function then why do you need to call it onSubmit of form. Also can you add the definition of your `_handleButton1` functions

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution so thought to share. This worked.

```
render() {
    let buttons;
    if (!this.props.submitting) {
     buttons = (
        <div>
            <button className="button1" type="submit" onClick={(e)=>this._handleButton1(e)}>
               <IndexLink activeClassName="activeLink" to='/button1'>Button1</IndexLink>
            </button>

            <button className="button2" type="button" onClick={(e)=>this._handleButton2(e)}>
               <IndexLink activeClassName="activeLink" to='/button2'>Button2</IndexLink>
            </button>
        </div>
    )} else {
        buttons = (
        <div>                   
            <button disabled>Submit</button>
            <button disabled>Expenses</button>
        </div>
    )}
    return ({button})

}
```